# Calculating number of people ahead in queue pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with customer arrival date/time and customer seen time (all are seen the same day they arrive), and want to determine for each customer, the number of people ahead in the queue upon their arrival time.

So for instance, `df_have.head()`

```
    Cust_ID Arrive_Date Arrive_Time Seen_Time  Depart_Date   Depart_Time    
0   475     2019-01-01  00:17:00    02:11:00   2019-01-01    11:30:00
1   331     2019-01-01  00:35:00    03:01:00   2019-01-01    07:35:00
2   434     2019-01-01  00:55:00    01:08:00   2019-01-01    01:18:00
```

What I want to do is, using the all my columns, determine the number of customers ahead in the queue of a customer before they are seen.

So for example, Customer 1 has 1 person ahead of him - Customer 0 - who arrived before Customer 1 and is seen before Customer 1 is seen.

Two rules can be used to see if there is another customer ahead in the queue.

**Rule 1: Eligibility check** if `Arrival_Date & Arrival_Time (incoming customer)` `<=` `Depart_Date & Depart_Time  (previous customers)` [existing customers must still be in the system to be ahead in the queue]

**Rule 2: Queue check** if `Seen_Time (incoming customer)` `>` `Seen_Time (previous customers)` [existing customers must be seen before to be ahead in the queue]

If both of these rules are met, there is someone ahead in the queue. Otherwise, there is no one ahead in the queue.

In this example, we can see there are 1 people ahead of `Customer 475`, since rule 2 fails:

**Rule 1:** `Arrival_Date & Arrival_Time (cust 475) <= Depart_Date & Depart_Time (cust 331,434)`

**Rule 2:**  `Seen_Time (cust 475) > Seen_Time (cust 434)`

Similarly, for Customer 331:

**Rule 1:** `Arrival_Date & Arrival_Time (cust 331) <= Depart_Date & Depart_Time (cust 475,434)`

**Rule 2:**  `Seen_Time (cust 331) > Seen_Time (cust 475,434)`

So there are two people ahead in the queue.

So the output would then be:

`df_want.head()`

```
    Cust_ID Arrive_Date Arrive_Time Seen_Time   People_Ahead 
0   475     2019-01-01  00:17:00    02:11:00    1   
1   331     2019-01-01  00:35:00    03:01:00    2   
2   434     2019-01-01  00:55:00    01:08:00    0
```

I am not sure how to code in these two rules, so any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, I worked as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

df['Arrive'] = df.apply(lambda cust: datetime.strptime(cust.Arrive_Date + ' ' + cust.Arrive_Time, '%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)
df['Seen'] = df.apply(lambda cust: datetime.strptime(cust.Arrive_Date + ' ' + cust.Seen_Time, '%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)
df['Depart'] = df.apply(lambda cust: datetime.strptime(cust.Depart_Date + ' ' + cust.Depart_Time, '%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S'), axis=1)
df['People_Ahead'] = df.apply(lambda cust: sum((cust.Arrive <= df['Depart']) & (cust.Seen > df['Seen'])), axis=1)
df[['Cust_ID', 'Arrive_Date', 'Arrive_Time', 'Seen_Time', 'People_Ahead']]
```